# SQL Check If Exists Value Less than Min

Tags: sql, case

TABLE1

```
STUDENT DATE    SUBJECT
------------------------
1   2018-11-13  HISTORY
1   2018-11-14  HISTORY
1   2018-11-15  HISTORY
1   2018-11-15  ART
1   2018-11-12  ENGLISH
1   2018-11-14  ENGLISH
2   2018-11-14  ENGLISH
2   2018-11-13  ENGLISH
2   2018-11-12  ART
3   2018-11-12  HISTORY
3   2018-11-15  ENGLISH
3   2018-11-14  SCIENCE
3   2018-11-14  ART
```

I have `TABLE1` and wish to create `TABLE2` which is:

- For every `STUDENT`, find the minimum (`DATE`) when `SUBJECT = HISTORY`, then check if there are any values of DATE when SUBJECT != HISTORY that are BETWEEN:

  WANTCOL = 1 IF DATE(SUBJECT != HISTORY) < MINIMUM(DATE) WHEN SUBJECT = HISTORY AND
  DATE(SUBJECT != HISTORY) > DATEADD(MONTHS, -6, MINIMUM(DATE) WHEN SUBJECT = HISTORY) OTHERWISE EQUALS TO 0

TABLE2 should be:

```
STUDENT WANTCOL
----------------
   1        1
   3        0
```

Here are some of my attempts

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    STUDENT,
    CASE 
        WHEN (DATE < (SELECT MIN(DATE) 
                      FROM TABLE1 
                      WHERE SUBJECT = 'HISTORY' 
                      GROUP BY STUDENT) 
            AND SUBJECT != HISTORY PARITION OVER (STUDENT) 
            AND DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM TABLE1 WHERE SUBJECT = 'HISTORY' GROUP BY STUDENT) FROM TABLE1 WHERE SUBJECT != HISTORY 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS WANTCOL
FROM 
    TABLE1
```

Comment: I don't see how your data results in Student 1 has Wantcol = 1; The minimum date that's not history is `2018-11-12` which is obviously not > `2019-05-13` (min history date + 6 months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your partial query and description, does the following work for you?

Pre-aggregate the data and then use a case expression to determine final value:

```
with d as (
  select student, 
  Min(case when subject = 'HISTORY' then date end) Hist, 
  Min(case when subject != 'HISTORY' then date end) NotHist
  from t
  group by student
)
select Student,
  case when NotHist < Hist and NotHist >= DateAdd(month, -6, Hist) then 1 else 0 end  Wantcol
from d
where Hist is not null;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dkwrJvNa)